# Is there a fluent way to continue from FluentIterable.index?

Tags: java, guava, fluent-interface

[FluentIterable.index](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html#index(com.google.common.base.Function)) returns an `ImmutableListMultimap`, which ceases to be fluent.
That means if I want to transform the existing map I will have to wrap the entire thing in another FluentIterable again, and the ugliness that results defeats the purpose of being fluent.

```
FluentIterable.from(
    FluentIterable
        .from(list)
        .index(...)
        .asMap().entrySet()) // this is less than ideal too
        // Ideally I want to transform here so that I don't need the other .from call
    .transform(....)
```

Is there a more fluent way to achieve this with guava? (without Java 8)

Comment: I'll probably get a lot of down-votes if I post this as the answer so I'll just post it here as a comment: If you want fluent iterables, lists, maps, sets, etc. for the JDK then you might be better off using a different JVM language (e.g. [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/)).

Comment: @mfulton26: Kotlin's great, but if the OP can't use Java 8 (which also has these features) they're probably not going to be able to use Kotlin either.